Внешний сервер Pylance для VSCode
Я использую VSCode с расширением Python. Анализ кода на ноутбуке довольно долгий. А на телефоне всё работает гораздо быстрее. Ноутбук и телефон находятся в одной локальной сети. Можно ли отправлять код Python на анализ на другое устройство?
На телефоне у меня стоит Termux, думаю туда можно поставить нужные программы. А если нет, есть сервер Ubuntu, на котором всё точно должно работать

Ноутбук: Windows 10, Python 3.12, локальная сеть
Телефон: Android 13, Python 3.11, локальная сеть
Сервер: Ubuntu, Python 3.10, открытый IP


Если надо, на сервер могу поставить Python 3.11. И могу дать более подробную информацию об устройствах: на ноуте через AIDA64, на телефоне и сервере через neofetch

2 недели и тишина
